# All symplectic manifolds have $Mp^c$-structures?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $(M,\omega)$ be a symplectic manifold, and $Mp^c(n)=Mp(n)\times_{\mathbb Z_2}U(1)$ which $Mp(n)$ here is Metaplectic group which is the double cover of symplectic group. I am looking for a nesessary and sufficient condition which $M$ has [$Mp^c(n)$-structure.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1307.1634)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no obstruction to the existence of $\mathrm{Mp}^c$ structures on $(TM,\omega)$ or more generally any symplectic vector bundle $(E,\omega)\to M$. The set of their equivalence classes identifies with $H^2(M,\mathbf Z)$. This is all in [Rawnsley-Robinson 1989](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1015418), pp. 3, 46, 55 who quote also [Forger-Hess 1979](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103904723), p. 272.

Comment: Thanks, are there any other such Mpc structures , except $spin^c$,  $pin$ or, $Mp$, $Ml$, metalinear structures, which $(M,\omega)$ always admit it ?